# Issue displaying LINQ query results in a grid in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I received some help here with the following LINQ query, but am still struggling with it.  The result I'm trying to obtain is to display some attributes and their values from an xml file in a DataGridView control.  I'm calling my method from a button click and am trying to pass back the list for display in the grid.  Here is an example of the row:

```
<z:row CenterCode="JAX" CenterName="Jacksonville" Version="1.0" NextExport="66742" NextImport="29756" LastImportTime="2015-06-10T14:48:33" FtpProxyServer="" FtpUserName="" FtpPassword="" ResetImportID="False"/>
```

Here is the method:

```
        public static List<string[]> MonitorCounts(string upperLimit)
    {
        // Load xml
        XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\XML\Configuration.xml");
        XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
        Int32 limit = Convert.ToInt32(upperLimit);
        var elementQuery = xmldoc.Descendants(z + "row").Where(e => (long?)e.Attribute("NextExport") > limit | (long?)e.Attribute("NextImport") > limit);
        var attributes = elementQuery.Select(e => e.Attributes().Select(a => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a.Name.LocalName, (string)a)).ToList()).ToList();

        return attributes;
    }
```

My questions are how to select only specific attributes and values in attributes.  If I do something like this:

```
var attributes = elementQuery.Select(e =>  e.Attributes("CenterName").Select(a => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a.Name.LocalName, (string)a)).ToList()).ToList();
```

then this is returned:

```
[0] = {[CenterName, Jacksonville]}
```

I need to select this and 4 others.  I'm also getting a convrsion error  - Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>`.  Appreciate any pointers to help me along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem.  Here is what I did:

Created a class for the attributes needed:

```
    public class dataRow
{
    public string CenterName { get; set; }
    public string CenterCode { get; set; }
    public string NextImport { get; set; }
    public string NextExport { get; set; }
    public string LastImportTime { get; set; }
}
```

Selected the results into it:

```
            List<dataRow> dataRows = elementQuery.Select( e =>  new dataRow 
        { CenterName = (string)e.Attribute("CenterName"),
          CenterCode = (string)e.Attribute("CenterCode"),
          NextImport = (string)e.Attribute("NextImport"),
          NextExport = (string)e.Attribute("NextExport"),
          LastImportTime = (string)e.Attribute("LastImportTime") }).ToList();
```

Changed my method to return the correct object:

```
public static List<dataRow> MonitorCounts(string upperLimit)
```

Set my grids datasource to the method return:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = xmlProcessing.MonitorCounts(tbxUpperLimit.Text.ToString());

return dataRows;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous type:

```
var attributes =
    elementQuery.Select(e => new
        {
            CenterName = (string)e.Attribute["CenterName"],
            Version = (string)e.Attribute["Version"],
            // more attributes
        }).ToList();
```

You can't however return this from the method in a useful way. So if you really need both the attribute name and the attribute value as strings, try this approach instead:

```
var attributes =
    elementQuery.Select(e => new []
        {
            Tuple.Create("CenterName", (string)e.Attribute["CenterName"]),
            Tuple.Create("Version", (string)e.Attribute["Version"]),
            // more attributes
        }).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

The return type of your method now has to be `List<Tuple<string, string>>`.

And finally, if you actually need a `List<string[]>` as the return type, use this code:

```
var attributes =
    elementQuery.Select(e => new []
        {
            new [] { "CenterName", (string)e.Attribute["CenterName"] },
            new [] { "Version", (string)e.Attribute["Version"] },
            // more attributes
        }).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: Will I be able to populate the grid with an anonymous type?  This is resulting in the folowing:  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'

Comment: @Brian: Most likely, yes, but you won't be able to easily return it from a method. Please check my update for another approach.